# Set color for the first character in a cell of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to Winform C#. I have a question: Are there any ways to set color for the first character in a cell of DataGridView?
Thank you!

Comment: No, you would have to owner-draw the cell in the CellPainting event.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, I'll try this! @TaW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling the CellPainting event is the right way to do it. Here is a code snippet applying your requirement to specific cell excluding the grid column headers.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()) && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        // Current cell pending to be painted.
        var currentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        // Cell that needs to be painted. In this case the first cell of the first row.
        var cellToBePainted = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];

        if (currentCell == cellToBePainted)
        {
            using (Brush customColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
            using (Brush cellDefaultBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor))
            {
                string fullText = e.Value.ToString();
                string firstChar = fullText[0].ToString();
                string restOfTheText = fullText.Substring(1);

                e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                Rectangle cellRect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Location, e.CellBounds.Size);
                Size entireTextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(fullText, e.CellStyle.Font);

                Size firstCharSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(fullText[0].ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(fullText[0].ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, customColor, cellRect);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(restOfTheText))
                {
                    Size restOfTheTextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(restOfTheText, e.CellStyle.Font);
                    cellRect.X += (entireTextSize.Width - restOfTheTextSize.Width);
                    cellRect.Width = e.CellBounds.Width;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(restOfTheText, e.CellStyle.Font, cellDefaultBrush, cellRect);
                }

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if I want to apply for a specific cell, what can I modify?

Comment: You can get the current cell in the handler as follows: var currentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

Comment: I updated my initial answer to check for particular cell.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh! This time it doesn't work! All contents of cells are black.

Comment: The cell in the upper left corner should be painted with first character in red. You can even replace my code with var cellToBePainted = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell. This is working on my side.